# phonegap push plugin v1.10.4 in firebase cloud message for support

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

Because of some factors, I need to use the phonegap-push-plugin v1.x version.

I use ionic, plugin to add phonegap-push-plugin.

I use Firebase to send a message and I never receive any messages.

Ionic Info

cli packages: (C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.3
npm               : 6.2.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Should Firebase still support GCM now?
Please clarify this question together, thank you

Comment: We all had our problem understanding the Observable in the post to Firebase. So maybe start and see if you POST to Firebase is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegp-push-plugin V1.x supports only GCM push server. But its been depreciated as per the google official site https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

For Firebase, you need to use Phonegp-push-plugin V2.x

Comment: thanks for your advice.
In fact, I have tried the phonegap-push-plugin v.2.x version, I can receive the firebase message.
So phonegap-push-plugin v.1.x version, it is determined to be unusable, Did i get that right ?